# Performing a RESTcall in Mocha usning node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, request, mocha.js

I Am trying to perform a REST call in Mocha. I´tried to use the "request" framework to login at auth0.
The REST call is correct, I tried the same data in Postman and got the correct answer.

Now I am trying to implement the call in our test, but this doesn't work.
The methode doesn't open the call-back function and I'm not getting any answer from the server. In the backend-log I could see, that the call doesn't get through to the backend, and no login is performed.
I tried several different methods from XMLHttpRequest to the request library.

Here the code I am using:

```
var should = require("should");
var assert = require('assert');
var request = require("request");

var authToken ='test';
var url = 'https://*****.eu.auth0.com/oauth/ro';

describe('auth0', function() {
    describe('Login', function() {
        it('should return authToken if user data is valid', function() {
            //REST call to login

            request.post({url:"https://********.eu.auth0.com/oauth/ro",
                    form: {
                                client_id:'*******************',
                                username:'*******************',
                                password:'*******************',
                                connection:'Username-Password-Authentication',
                                grant_type:'password',
                                scope:'openid'}},
                function(err,httpResponse,body){
                    console.log('entered call-back function');
                    console.log(httpResponse);

                });
            console.log('accessToken: ' + authToken);
        });
    });
});
```

And here is what I get after running the code:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\*******\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha" --ui bdd --reporter "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 2016.2.2\plugins\NodeJS\js\mocha-intellij\lib\mochaIntellijReporter.js" "C:\Users\*********\Desktop\********\Testing"

accessToken:test

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Hope you could help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the test run `async`. You can add a argument in the mocha callback and then invoque it when the request is done:

```
it('should return authToken if user data is valid', function(done) {
    //REST call to login
    request.post({
            url: "https://********.eu.auth0.com/oauth/ro",
            form: {
                client_id: '*******************',
                username: '*******************',
                password: '*******************',
                connection: 'Username-Password-Authentication',
                grant_type: 'password',
                scope: 'openid'
            }
        },
        function(err, httpResponse, body) {
            console.log('entered call-back function');
            console.log(httpResponse);
            done(); // <-- here you tell mocha the async part is done
        });
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! This works. I thought about it's a problem cause it is async but didn't found this.